# How to detect the difference between an application buffer and text editing?

Tags: minor-mode

I have created a minor mode which has the option to be enabled globally via `define-globalized-minor-mode`.

This mode is intended to be used for text editing, however the globalized version gets enabled for buffers such as `package-menu-mode` (the package list view), where it doesn't make sense.

What is a good way to differentiate text editing buffers from *application* buffers such as IRC, email, games ... etc.

Comment: How about using `derived-mode-p` and/or `memq` with a list of major-modes to include and/or exclude?

Comment: I think I've found this `(derived-mode-p 'special-mode)` seems to do what I want, although it doesn't seem like such a common thing to check - at least I don't see other packages doing this very much.

Comment: And .... you can include several major-modes as arguments to `derived-mode-p` if so desired ....

Comment: You can turn it around. You can enable it for modes that inherit from `prog-mode` and `text-mode`, plus a user-configurable list. I've use this approach (sometimes with an "avoid" list) in several of my packages, e.g https://github.com/Lindydancer/dynamic-spaces